# WinSCP from Unix to Windows - Conserving timestamp, ownership and permissions

Tags: windows, unix, file-permissions, winscp, transfer

I'm migrating a number of folders from a Unix box to a Windows server, and I want to maintain the folder structure, permissions, ownership (user and group), and ideally timestamps of the original files.

From what I've been able to gather online it seems like WinSCP would do the job just fine, providing I disable the "resume" option. I just wanted to double check if this was feasible and if there was another option I hadn't thought of, before go-live?

Are there any specific settings I need to input? Can WinSCP conserve all of the above?

Cheers,
Mark

Comment: There is no good match between file attributes in Unix and Windows. The access and update time stamps correspond, but there is nothing in Windows file systems corresponding to the user-group-other permissions, and there are no read or execute permissions: only Linux write permission corresponds with the converse of read-only in Windows. It might be possible to use Windows ACLs to implement a correspondence with some of the Linux attributes, but I doubt that `WinSCP` does this.

Comment: @AFH Is there a way to script it in that case? If I get a list of all files / folders owned by a specific user, is there a script I could run on the Windows machine that would assign the right ownership to all files from a .txt file or something like that?

Comment: Unix `find` will create those lists, but I have not used Windows ACLs to any extent, so others will need to advise on how to map into equivalent `cacls` commands. However, note that some of the ACL permissions are still a poor match, especially on directories, eg delete/rename access is implemented by permissions on the parent directory in Linux, but at a file level in Windows. Remember that there is no execution permission in Windows: all readable files are executable (assuming it is meaningful to do so, depending on a combination of the file extension and the magic number at the start).

Comment: Life may be easier in the future - see [here](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/03/30/run-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows/) - and I shall be very interested to see if they will implement file attributes, or simply make all files fully accessible (or not writeable if read-only) and owned by a single user, as in the example, and as happens currently if you view a Windows share from Linux using Samba.

Comment: @AFH: That's partly true & partly complete nonsense. Windows NT has had "Read" and "Execute" permissions since day one – just take a look at the same ACLs you _yourself_ mention. The "Execute" permission _is_ honored for files, it's merely _set by default_ (and CreateProcess() doesn't care about the extension much, it's mainly the graphical shell that does – you can rename calc.exe to calc.tmp and successfully run it via Command Prompt).

Comment: @AFH: (The POSIX user/group/other permission bits are just a limited form of ACLs – some programs pretend they're POSIX ACL entries, which can be easily expanded to NTFS ACLs... Though you're right that WinSCP doesn't bother doing that – but I'd guess because the _user accounts_ are damn near impossible to conveniently map across systems.)

Comment: @grawity - I stand corrected, of course: I said I was no expert on ACL, though I have worked with Unix since the 80s. I was basing my comment on the permissions settable by `cacls`, which are Read, Write, Change, Full and None. So how do you make a file readable, but not executable, or vice versa for a directory? I know that .EXE files can be renamed to any other extension, because of the magic number, but I know of no way to execute a batch script file called `batch.sh`, so I think my summary (combination of extension and magic number) is correct.

Comment: @AFH: The graphical Security dialog in Win2000+, or `icacls` in Win2003+, are a bit more expressive – e.g. `icacls foo /grant fred:(oi)(ci)(r) /grant martin:(rx)`. (When exporting a Linux /home over Samba, the lack of +x on .exe files is very noticeable.)  On directories, +x has identical meaning too ("Traverse folder / Execute file"), but it's ignored by default for some weird reasons – research "SeChangeNotifyPrivilege" aka "Bypass traverse checking".

Comment: @grawity - Thanks, I didn't know about `icacls`. It explains a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinSCP does [preserve timestamps](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_transfer_custom#common) by default (and you do not have to disable the "resume support").

WinSCP cannot not preserve the ownership and the permissions. There's hardly any way to do that automatically. First you would have to establish 1:1 mapping from *nix users and groups to those on Windows. Only then it makes sense to start mapping *nix permissions to Windows ACLs. I'm not aware of any tool capable of that.

Comment: If SFTP provides user names (rather than UIDs), that would be possible – but then there's the problem of requiring root or Administrator rights to actually _set_ the correct owner on newly downloaded files...